# Services paid in Bitcoin

Tags: services

I am interested in what other internet and other communication services out there are accepting Bitcoins for payment.
I know of http://mullvad.net/ for VPN and a few others, http://www.chundle.com/bitcoin for Usenet.

I doubt there are any ISPs yet or cell services.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too localized.  The answers will change over time (perhaps very quickly) thus thwarting this site's intention to be an enduring reference.

Answer (score 3):

[Bitcoin Torrents](http://www.bitcointorrentz.com/) lets you use their uber-fast servers to download a torrent.  Then you can stream it from there at a consistent rate.  Very nice idea!